# Ternary with boolean condition in c#

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

If I am to write this piece of code, it works fine with the normal 'if-else' layout.

```
if(isOn)
{
    i = 10;
}
else
{
    i = 20;
}
```

Although I am unsure how to convert this using the ternary operator

```
        isOn = true ? i = 1 : i = 0;
```

> Error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicitly conversion between 'void' and 'void'.

EDIT:
Answer = `i = isOn ? 10 : 20;`

Is it possible to do this with methods?

```
if(isOn)
{
    foo();
}
else
{
    bar();
}
```

Comment: Edited to add method question.

Comment: For your edit:, why do you want to do that with methods ? isn't your `if` clear enough ? also it depends what these methods are returning. If they are not returning anything `void` then I believe you can't use  the ternary operators.

Comment: If you have a new question then ask a separate question, don't update the existing questions with a new question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try the following.  BTW, it only works for value assignments not method calls.

```
i = isOn ? 10 : 20;
```

---

**Reference:**

- [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Perfect thank you. I have edited the question, do you know if it is possible with methods?

Comment: @MarcC:- What are your methods returning? Since the answer depends on that

Comment: The methods are void.

Comment: Updated the answer.  It's not possible for method calls.

Comment: For your edit: it will work for method calls, only if the methods are returning something. for example `i = isOn ? GetInt10() : GetInt20();` Where `GetInt10` and `GetInt20` returns `int` value.

Comment: @Habib very determined person can wrap `void` methods into lambda returning fake value for purely theoretical way of using `?:` with void functions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes :) but the point is the true/false **expression** should return something

Answer (score 5):

You may simply try this:

```
i = isOn? 10:20
```

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx) says:

> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   **first_expression** is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, **second_expression** is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one
>   of the two expressions is evaluated.

**EDIT:-**

If you want to  invoke `void` methods in a conditional operator, you can use delegates else it is not possible to use ternary operators for methods.

And if your methods are returning something then try like this:

```
i = isOn ? foo() : bar();    //assuming both methods return int
```

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track but a little off.
`i = isOn ? 10 : 20;`

Here `10` will be assigned to `i` if `isOn == true` and `20` will be assigned to `i` if `isOn == false`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an explanation that might help. The statement you're looking for is:

```
i = isOn ? 10 : 20;
```

And here's what that means:

```
(result) = (test) ? (value if test is true) : (value if test is false);
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
i = isOn ? 10 :20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
i = isOn ? 10 : 20
```

Answer (score -3):

You need:

```
i = true ? 10 : 20;
```

where `true` is your condition.

Comment: `isOn` is the `bool` (condition) specified in OP's code

Comment: The OP has already posted the answer to this. i = isOn ? 10 : 20;

Comment: `true` part was just for the OP to replace it with the condition.